# Can apps developed in the Ubuntu SDK be ported to Android?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, android, ubuntu-sdk

I am getting interested in creating Mobile Apps and I was wondering, can an app created in the Ubuntu SDK be deployed to work on Android or even iOS?

This isn't a huge deal, as I was using Eclipse to learn Android, but with the HTML5 abilities of the Ubuntu SDK it would great for developing as it would mean less learning of Java for me to start.

I read this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/354596/is-it-possible-to-deploy-an-ubuntu-sdk-app-to-android, but it didn't have any answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but

Ubuntu touch apps are written in QT and Qt apps can be ported to android using necseistas toolkit. 8ut may have to make considarable changes in the ui, because ubuntu toolkit is not supported in android, but still core code is portable

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible since apps for Android are written in Java and a special version of Java with a lot more classes that are just for Android. Ubuntu apps are written mostly in Python and C, not Java. There's your problem, you need to find apps written in Java and then they might go to port, but I wouldn't do it. It will be a lot of work for a thin chance of success.
And even if you get the Java app to start on your phone how will you interact with it? There will be no touch support or any other of the functions of your phone.